# Nullpointer Exception in List while on filtering - Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hi i am writing code for filtering specific data based on the input. if input not available in database it throwing `nullpointer exception` on the `list` since i am new in java i dont know how to solve this error

```
private String isCreditRatingValid(String isin) {

        System.out.println(isin);
        List<Credit_rating_details> result = Credit.stream()
                                            .filter(i-> i.getIssuer_id()
                          .contains(isin)).collect(Collectors.toList()); \\throwing NullPointerException on this line\\ 
        if(!result.isEmpty() ) {
            validCreditRating = result.get(0).getCredit_rating();
            return result.get(0).getCredit_rating();
        }else {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Paste the stack-trace. Also check if `Credit` is null

Comment: @NicholasK i am declaring credit 'static ArrayList<Credit_rating_details> Credit = null;'

Comment: If this static list `Credit` is null, obviously `null.stream()` is throwing the exception. Why don't you initialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment you are declaring it as

```
static ArrayList<Credit_rating_details> Credit = null;
```

which is causing the NPE as you are performing an operation on a `null` object. Change it to

```
static ArrayList<Credit_rating_details> Credit = new ArrayList<Credit_rating_details>();
```